# Change fancybox title async

Tags: jquery, fancybox

i am trying set up link for download original link for current picture.
Here is part of coce where i iniciate search for original pic url

```
afterLoad: function() {
                //this.title = '<a href="' + this.href + '">Download</a> ' + this.title;
                setOriginalPicForDownload(this.href);
            },
```

In short, code try find original pic file (diff size) using ajax and async url request. When is file found it may add link for download to title, but i do not know how. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolve it myself.
I have add id="fancybox-title" in the title element. 
In fancybox3 it is line 1310 and content (id already included)
current.caption.wrap = $('' + captionText + '')
I hope this someone helps